# Network printer install best practices

Tags: network-printer

I know an end-user (Windows 7 workstation part of a domain with NO admin privileges) can install a network printer (with static IP installed on a server) basically through two different ways:

1. adding a TCP/IP printer

   - Open Control Panel / Device and Printers    Click Add Printer
     Select Add Local Printer then click Next    Select create new port,
     choose Standard TCP/IP from menu, then click Next    Type static IP
     assigned to printer in Hostname or IP address field    (port name is
     automatically IP_129.107.X.X where X is defined by static IP)
     Check option to Query Printer and Automatically Select Driver then
     click Next    Click Finish in the Completing TCP/IP window    If
     driver is not found in list click Have Disk and select Driver when
     prompted then click OK    Use default name for printer then click
     Next    Select option to Not Share Printer then click Finish
2. Through the command: `\\SERVER_NAME\PRINTER_NAME` then double clicking
      on the printer icon

Are there any differences between these two methods, and which one is considered to be best practice?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is the one which you have evaluated in your environment and determined to be most appropriate for your admins and users.

Comment: So there's no difference..am I right? Both techniques are correct

Comment: They end in totally different configurations, neither of which is better for all environments.